# Create a wordpress login form to a non-wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two different websites. One is a non-wordpress website and the other one is blog made from wordpress framework. Is it possible to set up a login form to the non-wordpress site which redirects you to the wordpress blog dashboard if your login information is valid?

I tried creating a form in my website and set the action to my blog wp-login.php but instead of redirecting me to the dashboard it just displays the main wordpress login window but I am already logged in.

Comment: Please check updated solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531193/create-a-wordpress-login-form-to-a-non-wordpress-website/18531383#18531383

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use below form:**

```
<form method="post" action="http://yourdomain.com/blog/wp-login.php" id="loginform" name="loginform">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login">Username<br>
        <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="input" id="user_login" name="log"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Password<br>
        <input type="password" size="20" value="" class="input" id="user_pass" name="pwd"></label>
    </p>
    <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input type="checkbox" value="forever" id="rememberme" name="rememberme"> Remember Me</label></p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="button button-primary button-large" id="wp-submit" name="wp-submit">
        <input type="hidden" value="http://yourdomain.com/blog/wp-admin" name="redirect_to">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="testcookie">
    </p>
</form>
```

**Note:** Replace http://yourdomain.com/blog/ with your actual blog url

Comment: You are my savior!! had a problem with this part. - "value="http://yourdomain.com/blog/wp-admin" -Instead of just putting wp-admin, i included wp-login.php

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same thing as requested here and the solution of [Tahir Yasin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070732/tahir-yasin) works fine but if there is no test cookie('wordpress_test_cookie') then http://yourdomain.com/blog/wp-login.php will give you this error

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must
>   enable cookies to use WordPress.

Remove this line will fix the problem: `<input type="hidden" value="1" name="testcookie">`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways.

1. Cookies
2. Sessions

After your login is validated you store the information in an cookie/session, you send the users to your wordpress website. And the login page, checks if the desired session/cookie is available and if yes  you skip the login fase.

Comment: What cookie/session i need to create for get logged in wordpress??

Answer (score 0):

Just add `?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fsample.net%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1` to the action.